# How to change background color on selected item on a slicer in Power BI Desktop

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

I have horizontal button-type monthly slicer in my report. When I click on particular month - background color becomes black by default. 
Is any way to change that?

I want selected month become green color. 
I know how to change background on unselected items, but couldnt find the way to do the same on selected items.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible as of October 2017 release.
To achieve this effect, try a custom visual such as the Chiclet Slicer http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-custom-visuals-chiclet-slicer